# Misterious WebPageLibrary Feature

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, feature

In SharePoint Online, as part of the Modern Team site, there is a  **WebPageLibrary** **Web** feature with the ID d5a4ed08-27b9-4142-9804-45dec6fda126. This feature **also exists** in SharePoint 2019.

Does anyone know what this feature is supposed to do? I could not find any documentation describing it. I have checked if this feature exusted as part of a classic Team site and it it's not present there. So I am curious what this does exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Web feature **WebPageLibrary** is to enable Wiki Page Library template in the web.

If you disable the feature, you cannot use Wiki Page Library template to create a Wiki Page Library.

[image]